# RMarkdown - Change Inline Code Color

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using [inline code in RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html) and I would like all the text that is a result of inline code to be a different color in the document. In [this example](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html), I would like heat.colors to be red all over the document. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Or you can use `text_spec` in `kableExtra`. It literarily does the same thing but just a tiny bit more literal. See more [here](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#text_specification)

````
---
title: ''
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

This is inline code: `r text_spec(colnames(mtcars)[1], color = "red")`.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

### This is more inline code `r text_spec(colnames(mtcars)[2], color = "red")`.

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like:

````
---
title: ''
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{css echo=FALSE}
.custom-inline {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700
}
```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

This is inline code: `r sprintf("<span class='custom-inline'>%s</span>", colnames(mtcars)[1])`.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

### This is more inline code `r sprintf("<span class='custom-inline'>%s</span>", colnames(mtcars)[2])`.

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

to get:

[image]

The default templates do not wrap inline chunks in a classed `<span>` tag so you have to do it manually. You can make a function to do it, too.

Comment: This works, but I use a lot of inline code chunks. Could you help me figure out what the function to wrap them with span tags would look like?