# RMarkdown - Change Inline Code Color *without changing workflow*

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I teach an introductory statistics course using R Markdown in RStudio (Server). We have students knit to html_notebooks, and we often have them use inline code to report various elements of their statistical analyses. It'd be really helpful for grading purposes if we could have the result of inline code output in a different color -- that way we could easily see if they were indeed using inline code or if they copy-pasted a number from their output into raw text.

There's a couple of ideas for solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727217/rmarkdown-change-inline-code-color), but these won't super work in my case. These are introductory students who are generally kinda afraid of RStudio to begin with, so asking them to do anything complicated with `text_spec` or `sprintf` will likely cause mild riots. I really need something that won't change students' workflow at all.

I wonder if there's any way to configure things either on the backend in RStudio Server (maybe by [messing with `knitr`](https://github.com/VectorPosse/Intro_Stats/issues/10)?), or through some kind of `<style>` tag wizardry in the preamble, so that inline code will print its results in a different color.

Thanks!

EDIT: [Arthur Berg below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236137/9268253) has provided something that's almost exactly what I need. Here's a MWE:

````
---
title: "test knit_hook"
output: html_document
---

```{r, setup, include="FALSE"}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline=function(x){paste0("<span style=\"color: #0000FF;\">",
  x,"</span>")})
```

`r pi`
````

The only issue with this is that it doesn't work if I change to `html_notebook` in the YAML header and thus use the "Preview" button in the RStudio IDE. For external reasons, it's important for us to have the output type as `html_notebook`. Anyone know how we might modify this to get it to work with `html_notebook`?

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve this without changing the workflow too much is to create your own format  (e.g. `html_notebook2`) that is derived from the original but modifies the inline hook of knitr.

To get started you can check out this [document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/format-custom.html).

Basic steps include

1. Create a new R package
2. Within this project run `usethis::use_rmarkdown_template()`. This creates the folder structure for your new format.
3. Edit `skeleton.rmd` and `template.yaml`
4. Define your format in a R file which has the same name `html_notebook2.R`(kind of a convention).

The content of the `html_notebook2.R` file could be

```
#'@import knitr
set_hooks <- function() {
  default_hooks  <- knit_hooks$get()
  list(
    inline = function(x) {
      paste0("<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\">", x,"</span>")
  })
}

#' @importFrom rmarkdown output_format knitr_options pandoc_options html_notebook
#' @export
html_notebook2 = function() {
  output_format(
    knitr = knitr_options(knit_hooks = set_hooks()),
    pandoc = pandoc_options(to = "html"),
    clean_supporting = FALSE,
    base_format = html_notebook()
  )
}
```

In the first part we define a new inline hook which only changes the font color.
The second part is the definition of the new format.

After building and installing the package you can create a new rmarkdown document and use `output: packagename::html_notebook2` as the output format. All inline code output will be colored red using my code. Here is an example:

```
---
title: "Inline"
output: cformat::html_notebook2
---

## R Markdown

`r pi`
```

[image]

I created such a package and you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/martinschmelzer/cformat). Feel free to copy it and rename it (`cformat` is a pretty lame working title ;) ).

**Notice though that your students could change the color manually using HTML/CSS anyways.** A way around could be some kind of key generation using a certain rule (unknown to the students obviously). For each inline chunk a key is generated and embedded using

```
paste0("<span code=", key," style=\"color: #FF0000;\">", x,"</span>")
```

If a valid key is embedded, the output was generated using R and not simply copied.

Comment: For those who want to call a function instead: `red_color <- function(x){paste0("<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\">", as.character(x),"</span>")}`

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a fix to a simple R markdown document, adding this line changes the inline output to blue.

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline=function(x){paste0("<span style=\"color: #0000FF;\">", x,"</span>")})
```

Comment: This is very nearly exactly what I want. For clarity, this command needs to be in a setup chunk (a chunk labeled `{r, setup}` as the first chunk of the document.

HOWEVER, this only works when I'm knitting to an html_document; if I change to `output: html_notebook` in the YAML header, no dice. Do you know how I might get this to work when using `html_notebook` as the output type?