# R markdown change inline code background color for PDF

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

### How to change the background color for inline code elements in R-markdown PDF ?

Currently when I use the single back-ticks `like that`, the **background color** is not rendered when I knit the pdf (only the font, see the capture below). However everything is working for code blocks, so I am wondering if there are some tweaks around.

[image: inline code color not rendered]

I tested the answer from [issue 50727217](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727217/rmarkdown-change-inline-code-color), but the font is not rendered like 'code'.

I just want to display R-markdown inline code like markdown does.

#### Note

The inline code I want to have a gray background color will not be used to run code within R markdown, only to highlight some code elements (like a path, a function's name etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First run `library(kableExtra)`, then try the following inline code:  `` `r text_spec("(vectorizer.pickle)", color="white", background = "gray")` ``.

You can also make the text bold and play with **[hexadecimal colors](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/)** to find the right shade of gray you want:`` `r text_spec("(vectorizer.pickle)", bold = T, color="white", background = "#918C8B")` ``.

It worked for me. This is the pdf output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This works too for me, but I don't have the exact font as in code blocks. Here, the font in the ` `r text_spec(...)` ` is the same as the corpus. How to have the same font for ` `vectorizer.pickle` ` and ` `r text_spec(...)` ` elements ? I looked for the R markdown `text_spec` documentation, but did not found a font family argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that I did find the font-family element, but I was wrong... (you can see it in the edit history of my answer) It did compile, but when I looked to the result it had an error. I tried a couple of alternatives, like the extra_css argument, but no luck so far with font-family